# This question will get auto deleted - is it a winning choice?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, deleted-questions, comments

My **belief** is that if a question is **really** too broad, too bad, too much opinionable. The fact will prove it in a very short time.

The following question however had already got many interesting consideration in the comments. When it will be auto deleted every consideration will be lost.

The user couldn't answer the question since it have been locked for a reason which is not completely correct (see my answer to the comment).

Do you consider the deletion of question like this useful? Can you explain the pragmatical advantages reached by this?

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/236896/is-it-going-to-flex-or-showing-a-past-inflated-expectations?noredirect=1#comment474913_236896

Answer (score 6):

First off: they are not fully lost. Users with more than 10k rep will be able to see the question if they have the link to it.

Second deleting it avoids the ["broken window"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/broken-windows/info) effect. Or in other words because low quality crud remains on the site, it causes users to think that posting low quality crud is acceptable.